# Ajax JSON.parse doesn't fill all data

Tags: json, ajax, parsing, textarea

Sorry for the title, I have no idea how to title what is happening!

OK, So I have a edit modal that json.parse is putting the database data into. It is working and pulling all the DB info on console.log and it is working and filling in the title input box, but not the note textarea, it won't populate the data. I am not sure what I am missing, I am thinking it has something to do with the textarea, but not sure. Below is my code examples. Thank you for any help.

Form from Modal:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="edit-note-form" class="px-3">
          <input type="hidden" name="note_id" id="note_id">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter Title"
              required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Write Note Here" rows="6"
              required></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="editNote" id="editNoteBtn" value="Edit Note"
              class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg">
```

AJAX and JSON.parse code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".editBtn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get value from id
    edit_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      url: 'assets/php/process.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        edit_id: edit_id
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        data = JSON.parse(response);
        $('#note_id').val(data.note_id);
        $('#title').val(data.title);
        $('#note').val(data.note);
      }
    });
  });
```

Process.php handle:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_id'])) {
    $note_id = $_POST['edit_id'];

    $row = $cuser->edit_note($note_id);
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Method:

```
public function edit_note($note_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_id = :note_id";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['note_id' => $note_id]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Try checking the textarea value by inspect element after the title has been populated. Maybe data is there but its not visible. Or else you can try `.html()` or `.text()` instead of `.val()` on textarea

Comment: I don't see anything, that would prevent the text from showing up, the placeholder text shows up, but not the DB data. Only the title works. Tried html() and text() but still nothing. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Did you try `console.log($('#node'))` ? To see what's going on with the element

Comment: Figured out what was happening!

Answer (score 0):

The Add Modal and the Edit Modal both had fields of id="note". For whatever reason it didn't effect the title field but once I made the edit modal's note field to id="edit_note" It worked fine. Thanks to Beshamber Chaukhwan for reminding me to console.log($("#note") it let me know there were two fields.

Comment: Happy to help 